# Printing sub reports on a new page in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report in which I have added two sub reports in details b and details c respectively but I want to show sub reports on new page. I used page break formula but its not working.
Can anyone suggest me any other solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if they are all in the same section,
add sections so that they are each in their own section
then go to Section Expert for each section and on the paging tab select new page before

Comment: each report is in different section and thank you, it worked (Y)

Comment: if it helped you, please select my answer or up vote will do. thanks!